# What is the easiest way to create sequence with entity framework code first approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I want to use a sequence in ms sql-server to generate auto increment number for me without a table, and my application is using entity framework 4.4 + code first + sql-server 2008. What is the easiest way to create it and retrieve its value?

Answer (score 0):

Just add [Key] on top of your property. It should be int by the way.
You will need to add DataAnnotations reference to your project.

Comment: I should said "generate auto increment number for me without a table"

Comment: What would be the purpose of having an inc number without a table?

Comment: I use Sequences in DB2 when I want an ID that is unique across multiple tables.  It's far more efficient than creating a view to determine max ID, and prevents multiple connections grabbing the same max value before the inserts are committed.  See this [msdn blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008.aspx)